# Given Date, Asked to print the next date

Tags: python, date

```
date = raw_input()
while date!="END" or date!="end":
    day  = date[0:2]
    month = date[3:5]
    monthsingle = date[3:5]
    monthsingle =str(int(monthsingle))
    monthsingle = int(monthsingle)
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is assign the month's number to `monthsingle` to use it later in my code. The problem is the user is allowed to type "02" for February. How can I do this without this error:

```
monthsingle =str(int(monthsingle))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: You should use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module for this.

Comment: I am not allowed to use modules.

Comment: In which case, you should possibly *do your own homework.*

Comment: plz provide with the input that you are giving ?

Comment: It's appropriate to refer to a [meta discussion on the topic of homework and SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/173950) here.

Comment: It is not a problem that the user is allowed to type `02` for February.  The expression `int(02)` is legal and does what you would expect.  Explicitly specifying the conversion base is also legal and also does what you would expect: `int('02', 10)`  But you need to handle whatever the user types, and the user could just type `xxxxx` (which would definitely cause an error).

Answer (score 1):

If the user input is less than four characters long, `date[3:5]` will be the empty string.

You could check that the input string is valid before trying to convert it to an integer, or catch the exception and give the user a helpful error message. Unexpected user input should not cause your program to crash.

```
while True:
    print('Please enter a date in format "dd/mm" or "end".')
    date = raw_input()  # use input() if you use python 3
    if date.lower() == 'end':
        print('good bye')
        break
    try:
        day = int(date[0:2])
        month = int(date[3:5])
        print('Day is %d and month is %d' % (day, month))
        # Day and month are integers. 
        # You should check that it's a real date as well.
    except ValueError:
        # could not convert to integer
        print('invalid input!')
```

Comment: It's best to catch the error, and handle it, rather than trying to predict when it might happen and avoid it.  Also, please don't use a backslash in the error message date format... a forward slash or a hyphen would be better:  `print('invalid input. Use date format "dd/mm".')`

Answer (score 0):

In this implementation you can trim '0' at the begining:

```
monthsingle = date[3:5].lstrip('0')
```

Or check date[3:5]: it seems like there is a dot.

Answer (score 0):

[It is not a problem that the user is allowed to type 02 for February.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571884/given-date-asked-to-print-the-next-date/27577086#comment43570555_27571884) The error message indicates that the issue is that `monthsingle` is empty (`''`). If you slice a string beyond its end; you get an empty string.
It means that the input is not in `dd/mm` format.

To parse the date without using `datetime.strptime()` function:

```
while True:
    try:
        day, month = map(int, raw_input("Enter date dd/mm: ").split('/'))
        # validate day, month here...
    except ValueError:
        print 'invalid input, try again'
    else:
        break

# use day, month to get the next date...
# you could use datetime module to check your answer:
from datetime import date, timedelta
print(date(date.today().year, month, day) + timedelta(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate_next_date(day,month,year):
    #Start writing your code here
    if((year%400==0 or year%4==0) and month==2):
        next_day=day+1
        next_month=month
        next_year=year
    elif(month==2 and day==28):
        next_day=1
        next_month=month+1
        next_year=year
    elif(month==12 and day==31):
        next_day=1
        next_month=1
        next_year=year+1
    elif(day==31 ):
        next_day=1
        next_month=month+1
        next_year=year
    elif((day==30) and (month==4 or month==6 or month==9 or month==11)):
        next_day=1
        next_month=month+1
        next_year=year
    else:
        next_day=day+1
        next_month=month
        next_year=year




    print(next_day,"-",next_month,"-",next_year)


generate_next_date(28,2,2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Java**

> Implement a program to generate and display the next date of a given date. The date will be provided as day, month and year as shown in the below table. The output should be displayed in the format: day-month-year. Assumption: The input will always be a valid date.

```
class NextDate 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Implement your code here 
        int day = 31,month = 12, year=15,monthLength;
        year = 2000+year;
        char leap;
        
        if((year % 4==0) & (year % 100 == 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            leap = 'y';
        }
        else
        {
            leap = 'n';
        }

        if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
        {
            monthLength = 31;
        }
        else if(month == 2)
        {
            if(leap == 'y')
            {
                monthLength = 28;
            }
            else
            {
                monthLength = 29;
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            monthLength = 30;
        }
        
        if(day < monthLength)
        {
            day++;
        }
        else if(month == 12 & day == monthLength)
        {
            day = 1;
            month=1;
            year++;
        }
        System.out.println(day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
    }
}
```